# Linux kernel does not accept an ICMPv6 router advertisement but sends redirect to same address instead

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, dhcp, ipv6, icmp

I'm using dhcpcd to receive ICMPv6 router advertisements from my ISP on ppp0 and everything works after a fresh boot. However, some time later, upon a disconnect and ppp0 reconnection, this does not work anymore. tcpdump shows the kernel actually receives the RA, but instead of accepting it, it sends an ICMPv6 redirect. To the *same* address, which does not make any sense to me. Is this a bug? Why should it do this? I'd greatly appreciate any help. After a reboot, everything works again...
tcpdump-output:

```
23:06:27.174222 IP6 (class 0xc0, hlim 255, next-header UDP (17) payload length: 129) fe80::fa13:8ff:fe1c:1f11.547 > fe80::2daf:5d1f:81c8:546.546: [udp sum ok] dhcp6 reply (xid=821aa (server-ID hwaddr type 1 f813081c1f11) (client-ID hwaddr/time type 1 time 747094422 00085452ff66) (rap
id-commit) (IA_PD IAID:2 T1:1800 T2:2880 (IA_PD-prefix <my_prefix> pltime:3600 vltime:86400)) (DNS-server 2a03:6880::1 2a03:6880::2))
23:06:27.174269 IP6 (hlim 255, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 216) fe80::2daf:5d1f:81c8:546 > fe80::fa13:8ff:fe1c:1f11: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, redirect, length 216, fe80::2daf:5d1f:81c8:546 to fe80::2daf:5d1f:81c8:546
```

The *:1f11 address is my isp, mine is *:546.
Does anybody have a clever idea how to debug this one or what the cause for this weird redirect could be?

Additional info:
gentoo linux, kernel 6.5.1-gentoo, dhcpcd 10.0.2. It also happened with earlier kernel versions though.

Comment: You probably should provide addresses and especially routes before and after the problem.